# Is it possible to have separate DB for each areas in .net-core along with project's DB?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-areas

I need to create separate database for area in a project. I don't want to join two database together. is it possible or not ?

Actually I wanted to have totally separated projects in one solution but this way I have some issue with routes (only one of them is accessible by routes) so i decided to try area but still I need to have more than one DBs in a project

Comment: please collaborate more , what is the reason you need to have another database?

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. you tried? What bothered you to succeed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

I do not know how you connect to your database, but in your `appsettings.json` file, put two connection strings with different names for different DB's.